# installing mysql 5.7 on macOS m1 using homebrew

Tags: mysql, homebrew, apple-m1, mysql-5.7

when I am running `brew install mysql@5.7` on MacBook with an m1 chip, I am getting this error.

```
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

what can I do about it?

Comment: `brew doctor` gives a clean bill of health?

Answer (score 0):

```
git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master
```

this will switch to master, then run

```
brew doctor
```

this should run without any error.

If there is no error you can install anything with brew install.

ex:

> brew install mysql@5.7

Answer (score -1):

May be you should run `brew update` first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).